# How to optimize a UILocalNotification process

Tags: cocoa, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to send multiple localNofications using a fetch request on an entity
And though this code works fine

```
   NSFetchRequest *myRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active == YES"];
  [myRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entry" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
  [myRequest setPredicate:predicate];
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: myRequest error: &error];
  if (fetchedObjects == nil){
 // Deal with error...
 }

// We fill the NSMutableArray with the values of the fetch
self.activeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"textbody"]];
[self scheduleAlarms:[self.activeList objectAtIndex:0]];
[fetchedObjects release]; //this line crashes the app
```

1) if I release fetchedObjects, the app crashes. Aren't I supposed to release it ?

2) Could I use the localNotif.userinfo to optimize the code instead of calling a method to schedule each localNotification with the strings in my activeList ? I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) executeFetchRequest returns an autoreleased NSArray, you don't need to release it manually

2) not clear what do you want to optimize...

Comment: Thanks. And by optimizing, I meant a means of not scheduling the local notifications one at a time, I know that it's possible to use the userinfo dictionary to set up the local notifications but the local notification reference guide is rather vague on how to implement it.